# Email finished but the send email window does not close?

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

my problem is that I programmed emailwindow and it does send emails, but when they are send or I want to close the window there´s nothing that happens.

Thats my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MessageUI


class ContactViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()


    @IBAction func email(_ sender: Any) {

        if !MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            let warnung = UIAlertController(title: "Email konnte nicht gesendet werden", message: "Dein Gerät unterstützt leider keine Email-Funktion.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            warnung.addAction(action1)
            self.present(warnung, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return

            } else {

                mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
                mail.setToRecipients(["team@example.com"])
                mail.setSubject("Message to you")
                mail.setMessageBody("Hello,\n", isHTML: false)

                present(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)

            func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                                       didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
                mail.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                print("Yes!")
                }


            }
        }
}
```

Here´s a screenshot of the mail window :
[Just click on this link!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1bYv.png)

Comment: Why is the delegate method INSIDE the `email(_sender:)` method, in it's `else` test?

Comment: Because I thought that it works better when it´s inside the else method

Comment: Note that your method `didFinishWithResult` was declared inside your IBAction email method. You need to move that method out of that IBAction method. It needs to be an instance method of your view controller

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func email(_ sender: Any) {

    if !MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        let warnung = UIAlertController(title: "Email konnte nicht gesendet werden", message: "Dein Gerät unterstützt leider keine Email-Funktion.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        warnung.addAction(action1)
        self.present(warnung, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return

        } else {

            mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mail.setToRecipients(["team@example.com"])
            mail.setSubject("Message to you")
            mail.setMessageBody("Hello,\n", isHTML: false)

            present(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                                   didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
            mail.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("Yes!")
}
```